# Cannot remove curly single quote character from file names, with batch file (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, characters

This works in a batch file to remove the letter "y" from all file names next to the batch file:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%A in ("*.*") do (
    SET ORIGINAL_FILENAME=%%~nxA
    echo.!ORIGINAL_FILENAME!

    SET MODIFIED_FILENAME=!ORIGINAL_FILENAME:y=!
    echo !MODIFIED_FILENAME!

    REN "!ORIGINAL_FILENAME!" "!MODIFIED_FILENAME!"
)
```

If I want to remove the curly single quote character from file names, it doesn't work:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%A in ("*.*") do (
    SET ORIGINAL_FILENAME=%%~nxA
    echo.!ORIGINAL_FILENAME!

    SET MODIFIED_FILENAME=!ORIGINAL_FILENAME:’=!
    echo !MODIFIED_FILENAME!

    REN "!ORIGINAL_FILENAME!" "!MODIFIED_FILENAME!"
)
```

Is there any way to do this without using Powershell?

I have also tried something called "jren.bat", listing the curly quote character alongside all the other characters it *can* remove and it also cannot remove this curly single quote character.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you certain the quote chars are the same as in the filenames, you could verify by seeing if this prints the filename: `echo .!ORIGINAL_FILENAME! | findstr /L '`

Comment: Yes it has to be the same character, because I am copying it from the filename and pasting it into the batch file. It's a weird curly version of the 'single quote'. I don't have that curly version on my (UK) keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution to this but it's no longer a problem because I just tested the batch file and it doesn't matter that the curly single quote isn't removed. I thought a certain program couldn't handle the character but that wasn't the reason the process wasn't completing and it's since been fixed.

I'll leave it as an open question in case there is a solution just because it's bugging me that the conventional way to remove that specific character, isn't working when it does work for normal alphanumeric characters.